# Is it possible that Hive table as source and Oracle table as target in Informatica developer tool with hive environment?

Tags: hive, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I want to use HIVE table as a source and Oracle table as target in my Informatica developer tool mapping with hive environment. Mean I want to run my Informatcia developer tool mapping in HIVE mode. Is it possible if yes then please let me know the steps.

Thanks

Comment: Please share description of the PROBLEM you're facing, instead of asking for full step-by-step how-tos. Make some effort, ask when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, You just need to change the execution engine.
Refer to Informatica BDM help document for the detailed steps

Answer (score 0):

You can create Oracle connection via sqoop and use it with any of the Hadoop engine in informatica bdm

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible using sqoop for oracle. But there is limitation that with sqoop you can only insert in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use PowerExchange for Hadoop to load data from PowerCenter to new Hive tables.
2. Source or targets will appear in PowerCenter as ODBC data sources or ODBC targets .